# Update java created Primefaces Chart from Bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, charts

I've created a pie chart in my bean and add this to a panel. Now I would update this chart from the bean, but the chart isn't updated. I've updated the model and this is correct, but why is the chart not?

Here's an image how does my page look like:
[image]

When I push the button, I would update my chart.

Here's my code to create the chart:

```
Panel p = (Panel) e.getComponent().getParent().getParent();
p.setStyle("width: 500px; height: 400px !important;");

p.getChildren().clear();

Application ap = facesContext.getApplication();
Chart chart = (Chart) ap.createComponent(facesContext, "org.primefaces.component.Chart",
        "org.primefaces.component.ChartRenderer");
chart.setId("chart" + chart.hashCode());

setTitle(p.getId(), msgs.get("dashboard_chart5_title"));

if (getMemberTrendStatsIsNotEmpty()) {
   HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) ap.createComponent(HtmlForm.COMPONENT_TYPE);
   form.setId("memberTrendForm");

   chart.setType("bar");
   chart.setId("memberTrend");
   chart.setModel(memberTrendStats);
   ValueExpression ve = ap.getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(facesContext.getELContext(),
                 "#{dashboardController.memberTrendStats}", PieChartModel.class);
   chart.setValueExpression("model", ve);
   form.getChildren().add(chart);

   OutputLabel out = (OutputLabel) ap.createComponent(OutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);
   out.setFor("yearsBack");
   out.setValue(msgs.get("dashboard_chart1_search") + ": ");
   form.getChildren().add(out);

   InputText in = (InputText) ap.createComponent(InputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
   in.setId("yearsBack");
   in.setValue(yearsBack);
   in.setStyle("margin-right:10px;");
   in.setType("number");

   NumberConverter nc = new NumberConverter();
   nc.setMaxFractionDigits(0);
   in.setConverter(nc);
   form.getChildren().add(in);

   CommandButton btn = (CommandButton) ap.createComponent(CommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
   btn.setValue(msgs.get("dashboard_chart1_update"));

   AjaxBehavior ab = new AjaxBehavior();
   ExpressionFactory ef = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
   MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(facesContext.getELContext(),
       "#{dashboardController.updateMemberTrend}",
       null,
       new Class[] { ActionEvent.class });
   ab.setListener(me);
   btn.addClientBehavior("submit", ab);
   btn.setProcess("@form");
   btn.setAjax(true);

   btn.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(me));

   form.getChildren().add(btn);

   p.getChildren().add(form);
} else {
   p.getChildren().add(getEmptyMessage());
}
```

And here's my code to refresh the chart:

```
msgs = langFacade.getLangProperty(facesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale().getLanguage());

InputText in = (InputText) findUIComponent("memberTrendForm:yearsBack");

if (in != null) {
    yearsBack = ((Long) in.getValue()).intValue();
}

createChartModels();

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("memberTrendForm:memberTrend");
```

Can someone help me with this problem?
Thx

Comment: When i press F5 in the Browser and execute the submit the chart is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I've found the solution, I've used the false model in the expression:

```
ValueExpression ve = ap.getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(facesContext.getELContext(),
                 "#{dashboardController.memberTrendStats}", BarChartModel.class);
chart.setValueExpression("model", ve);
```